# Windows .NET Core app can be independent from host? use own tls / cipher settings or must use always host/windows settings?

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, .net-core

I'm building some app that will run on Windows host as an `.exe` app
on a server where `tls 1.0` and `tls 1.1` are **disabled** in Windows settings / regedit / schannel - you know where.

So my question: is it possible to hardcode in that `.exe` tls 1.0 / 1.1 and be able to use it even if on hosts this versions are disabled?

Same question - can I add some cipher in C# code and force app to use it even if this cipher does not exists  / is not allowed on host reg settings?

I see on Linux, this is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/default-cipher-suites-for-tls-on-linux

But is it possible on a Windows host as well?
To be truly OS independent ?

Thanks and regards

----edit
real example for this question

we had a situation where tls versions was matching - both 1.2 but some ciphers(unsafe) was disabled in our system (`AES256-SHA / TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA` ) but enabled on legacy machine. and from .net i was unable to connect / error:`culd not create secure ssl/tls channel` .
but from python client or from postman from the same machine - it was working fine - so in this way was os independent ? thats real life example of this issue that im asking. - it was not easy to change cipher set on that legacy machine that finaly we did and .net started to connect ok.

Comment: What's the actual question behind this? Why not fix whatever service or site uses the obsolete algorithms? It's been 7 years since all clouds services started requiring TLS 1.2. In all *supported* Windows versions the obsolete algorithms are disabled, which is why you can't use them. If you do want them you can enable them through the registry.

Comment: it is just silli example but question is about is it possible. in corporate enviroment there is a lot legacy machines that do not supoort modern standards and sometimes it is the need. so i want to known if this is coupled or can be decoupled from host env. like python can for example...?

Comment: Python can't either. No language can make a library execute non-existent code, including removed TLS algorithms.  And those legacy machines already support the old algorithms, it's the *new* machines that have disabled them. You still haven't explained what the real question is

Comment: Are you trying to re-enable TLS 1.1 without telling the end user or their administrator? Otherwise, why  not just *ask* them to re-enable the algorithms? *Especially* in a corporate environment?

Comment: we had a situation where tls versions was matching - both 1.2 but some ciphers(unsafe) was disabled in our system (AES256-SHA) but enabled on legacy machine. and from .net i was unable to connect / error:culd not create secure ssl/tls channel . but from python client or from postman from the same machine - it was working fine - so in this way was os independent ? thats real life example of this issue that im asking. - it was not easy to change cipher set on that legacy machine that finaly we did and .net started to connect ok.

Comment: That's a very different question and has nothing to do with the OS or the TLS version. The link already shows how you can specify more algorithms. I suspect if you google for the actual algorithm name you'll find similar questions. `AES256-SHA` isn't helpful. All the algorithms in that link use SHA in some form and half the supported algorithms use AES256

Comment: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA  to be more specyfic. but the link is about that option in linux. i did not found similar info about windows thats why im asking. from my point of view eaither app can be os independent or not. if the answer is that TLS version canot be but ciphers can be - it will be god answer. I just want to known whats are the limitations here.